# Sql error on insert statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using a gridviews Row Updating to add edited fields into a table for monitoring. Everything seems to work except for the one value, as shown below.

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To colnum

        If e.OldValues(i).ToString() <> e.NewValues(i).ToString() Then
            Dim uid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(strUID)

            Dim UpC As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblAud (TN, FN, tID, OldValue, UserID) VALUES ('" + tN + "', '" + fn + "'," + tID + ", '"+ oldValue + "'," + uid + ")", con)

            UpC.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
    Next
```

If I display the userid to a text box, it shows the id fine, if I type a number in the sql in place of it, it works. Also the sql works if I take out the userid, but with it on I get an error "Input string was not in a correct format."
Also everything is added to the database twice, any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Create the SQL insert string in a separate variable.  Then you can look at it in the watch window and see what is happening.

Something like...

```
Dim SQl as String = 'INSERT INTO tblAud (TN, FN, tID, OldValue, UserID) VALUES ('" + tN + "', '" + fn + "'," + tID + ", '"+ oldValue + "'," + uid + ")"'
```

Comment: Did that but it made no difference. I can't use a watch window or any debugging, something about the server and database location..

Answer (score 0):

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Is generally associated with conversion.  Since you are converting a string to a number, that is the most likely culprit.  You can try a method like Int32.TryParse to validate the number and display an error message if it can't be parsed.  Note that `Convert.ToInt32` on an empty string or null will yield this error message as well.

Everything being added to the database twice could be because you are not actually using `e.OldValues(i)` in your INSERT query, but some other variable called `oldValue`.  It's hard to say without more code sample, but your best bet is to learn your debugging tools and watch what is happening.

Comment: TryParse still brings the same error. And using Convert.ToInt32 and displaying the value on a textbox displays a number, so I know it's not empty. As for the variable oldValue I did create it as a string from e.OldValues(i), I'll edit my post to add more code in.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding the id to a textbox and then using Textbox.text on the sql statement.